# PHPMyAdmin File Import Error

Tags: phpmyadmin

I can't seem to get PHPMYADMIN to import an SQL file properly as it is giving my the error:

> *No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP
>   configuration. See FAQ 1.16.*

**The documentation says:**

> The first things to check (or ask your host provider to check) are the
>   values of upload_max_filesize, memory_limit and post_max_size in the
>   php.ini configuration file. All of these three settings limit the
>   maximum size of data that can be submitted and handled by PHP. One
>   user also said that post_max_size and memory_limit need to be larger
>   than upload_max_filesize.

**Here's what I've done...**

Changed PHP.INI params

- upload_max_filesize = 1000M
- memory_limit = 1500M
- post_max_size = 1500M
- restarted Apache

I also tried different limit variables in hopes that maybe I was setting them too high... but that didn't matter. PHPMYADMIN confirms (on the import page) that the upload variable is set to "(Max: 1,000MiB)" but still no good. I am only trying to upload a file that is 5MB in size.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does the Apache error log say, if anything? Are you using SSL client certificates?

Comment: I know it's not really an answer, but do have access to the Command-line interface? You can probably use that to import the file, if you have access.

Comment: did you try to zip the file and upload it.?

Comment: I gave up on PHPMyAdmin and went back to old school - I used CLI.. #: mysql -u root {database} < file.sql

Answer (score 15):

I've just fixed this on my own dev machine. In /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf you can see where phpmyadmin is trying to store temp files, e.g.:

> php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp

Make sure this is writable by the user that apache runs as and has free space.

In my case, on my dev machine, I run apache as my own user rather than the normal www-data or apache user. That tmp dir wasn't writable by my user.

Answer (score 1):

For others with this problem not solved with PHP .ini settings, look in your html form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000" />
```

My form had a value lower than my php server settings.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem on Ubuntu 17, maybe because of the upgrade I've done. The problem was a not writable /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp so just run this code:

sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/

and then its works again.

Answer (score 0):

Add "/tmp/" in open_base_dir directive in /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

i was having this problem on php version 8.1,apache2 running on ubuntu
Steps to solve this problem:

1. login to your server via ssh
2. cd /etc/php/8.1(your php version)/apache2
3. nano php.ini
4. press ctrl+w and look for the line : upload_max_filesize
5. update with desired limit for example : upload_max_filesize = 512M
6. similarly look for post_max_size and update with desired value
7. ctrl+x then press y to save in nano editor
8. run command : sudo systemctl restart apache2 (to restart apache2)

Check the limit again it'll show the newly set limit