# File upload issue (NOT php.ini issue)

Tags: php, upload

I have been having trouble with my upload script. It uploads the album of photos to the users folder, it also creates a thumbnail for each and inserts a reference into the database. When testing it offline (using XAMPP) Everything uploads fine. However online seems to only work with a few files. Anything larger it will fail and not even run anything (It will output the message at the button as if nothing has been run).

At first i thought it was the PHP.ini file but i have set correct vaules for the album i was testing with. I checked the phpinfo() on the server to make sure the values were being applied. I have messed around with the settings to increase the post size etc. so i know that can't be the problem. Can't think what else it may be, please help!

PHP.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M 
post_max_size = 500M 
max_input_time = 60 
max_file_uploads = 100
```

Upload Script

```
require_once '../includes/connect.php';


if($_GET) {
  $username =  $_GET['id'];
  $result =mysqli_query($con, "SELECT acc_id FROM account WHERE username = '$username'");
  $userinfo = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $acc_id = $userinfo['acc_id'];
}

if(isset($_POST['sendfiles'])) 
{
  $album_name = $_POST['label'];
  $album_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $album_name);
  $sqlalbum = "INSERT INTO gallery_album (acc_id, user, title, date_created) VALUES ($acc_id, '$username', '$album_name', NOW())";
  mysqli_query($con, $sqlalbum);
  $album_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

  if(!is_dir( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/image/". $username ."/" . $album_name)) {
    mkdir( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/image/". $username ."/" . $album_name);
  }
  $uploaddir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/image/". $username ."/" . $album_name;

  foreach ($_FILES['photos']['name'] as $name => $value)
  {

    $nameofile = stripslashes($_FILES['photos']['name'][$name]);
    $extension = pathinfo($nameofile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $newfilename = uniqid() . "." . $extension;

    if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "JPG") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "JPEG") && 
       ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "PNG") && ($extension != "gif") && ($extension != "GIF") &&
       ($extension != "bmp") && ($extension != "BMP")) 
    {
    //print error message
      header('location: ../view/error');
    }
    else
    {

      $filename = $_FILES['photos']['name'][$name];
      $source = $_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name];   
      $target= $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."/image/". $username ."/". $album_name ."/". $newfilename;
      move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

      if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(JPG)$/', $filename)) {
          $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."/image/". $username ."/". $album_name ."/". $newfilename);
      } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)|(GIF)$/', $filename)) {
          $im = imagecreatefromgif($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."/image/". $username ."/". $album_name ."/". $newfilename);
      } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)|(PNG)$/', $filename)) {
          $im = imagecreatefrompng($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."/image/". $username ."/". $album_name ."/". $newfilename);
      } else if (preg_match('/[.](bmp)|(BMP)$/', $filename)) {
          header('location: ../view/error');
      }


      $ox = imagesx($im);
      $oy = imagesy($im);

      $nx = 400;
      $ny = floor($oy * (400 / $ox));

      $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);
      imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);
      imagejpeg($nm, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."/image/". $username ."/". $album_name ."/thumb". $newfilename);

      $sqlimage = "INSERT INTO gallery_image (filename, album_id, acc_id, user, album_title, date_created) VALUES ('$newfilename', $album_id, $acc_id, '$username', '$album_name', NOW())";
      mysqli_query($con, $sqlimage);
      $image_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

      $sqlrel = "INSERT INTO gallery_relation (acc_id, album_id, image_id) VALUES ('$acc_id', '$album_id', '$image_id')";
      if (!mysqli_query($con, $sqlrel)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }  

    }
  }
    $sqlalbum = "UPDATE gallery_album SET preview='$newfilename' WHERE album_id='$album_id'";
    mysqli_query($con, $sqlalbum);
    header('location: ../view/photos');
    //echo "Images uploaded successfully";
    //echo $acc_id . "  ";
    //echo $newfilename . "  ";
    //echo $newname;    
} else {
echo "upload has failed";
}
```

Edit: Here are the Request and response headers

Request

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:9744316
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWFXD7z91g1od2ZmU
Cookie:PHPSESSID=251c9c673446c0728aefb0b7b85ae4a8
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36
```

Response

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:37
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 28 Jan 2015 02:19:56 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache
Vary:User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.17
```

Comment: please add the request headers

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853301/phpmyadmin-file-import-error  could be helpful

Comment: Hey i added the headers, i did this by ruining the script and clicking on it, on the dev tools in chrome. Its the first time i've seen them so i could have copied them wrong, please let me know if i have, thanks

Comment: You sure your `max_input_time` of 60 seconds is long enough?

Comment: Your file upload size is 10mb, and your request body is pretty close to that. Are you certain all the files you're uploading are less than 10mb?

Comment: Also, is there a `memory_limit` set?

Comment: Yes i have played around with the values a lot and set them much higher before with the same results as i get now. Each image in my test album is no more then a 1MB and the whole album is under 10MB. i can't that being a problem. The memory limit is set to 128M which i can't seem to alter like the other values as i do not own the server.

Comment: Who is your hosting company? You said you changed some values. Are the values you provided the defaults? Because if they were changed it would require a restart of Apache to take effect. Have you checked the Apache logs for an error?

Comment: It is hosted with 123 reg, i can check the phpinfo from the site to see if the values have changed, which they do. Only a few i couldn't change like Memory_limit. I wouldn't know how to reset it and would assume that it would do it automatically